# How can I fix "Loading failed for the <script> with source" for ReactJS app

Tags: html, reactjs, build, yarnpkg

I have a simple one page website I made with ReactJS. After I use Yarn Build it successfully builds but when I try to run the index.html I see a blank page and in the console it shows this error. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I uploaded to hosting service it worked like a charm.